# Different numbers of votes cast are shown on the activity page and on the votes tab

Tags: support, voting, statistics, user-profile

This page says I have cast both 907 votes and 960 votes. Not that it matters, but why the difference?

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/210189/jon-mark-perry?tab=votes

Comment: 53 of the votes that you have cast were cast on now deleted content.

Comment: BTW the page you linked is not visible to other users. (Which is on purpose - voting is supposed to be anonymous. But any users have access to their votes tab: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up/down votes on since-deleted posts are [included in the total shown on Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048), and count toward badges.

However, they are not shown on the /votes tab. Why? I suppose it's just because someone coded the tab this way; I'm not aware of any explanation of this design.

The tabs "close, reopen, delete, and undelete" show votes on deleted posts, but only if you have enough reputation to see them (10K+). This is a [relatively recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235210).